# Form not passing file/picture through submit

Tags: php, html, forms, jquery-mobile

I'm working with php/html5 and i'm attempting to upload a file, but `$_FILES['picture']` never seems to contain anything. I've been through a lot of posts and looked for common fixes, but none of them seem to work, firstly, the code;

Form;

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="decodeQR.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000000" />
  <input type="file" name="picture" id="picture" value="picture" accept="picture/*" capture>
  <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

decodeQR.php;

```
<?php
include 'header.php';


$upload_status = FALSE;
if(isset($_FILES['picture']))
{
    echo 'picture set <br>';
}
else
{
    echo 'picture not set <br>';
}

if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
  {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  }

if (isset($_FILES['picture']) && file_exists($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name']))
{
    $image = $_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'];

    //~ Check if image is an image
    if (@getimagesize($image))
    {
        $upload_status = TRUE;
        //~ from here you can use yours image as $_FILES['picture']['name'], for example to copy it
        move_uploaded_file($image, realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/images/'.$_FILES['picture']['name']);

        //~ Also be noticed that the image curently is in OS tmp folder and if you dont copy it, it will be deleted after script execution.
    }
}
if ($upload_status)
{
    echo 'Image successfully uploaded. <br> <img src="images/'.$_FILES['picture']['name'].'">';
}
else
{
    echo 'nope.jpg';
}

?>
```

The output is always;

picture not set

nope.jpg

This means that `$_Files['picture']` is not set, and there are no errors in the files array.

As you can see from the code above i have already tried the following fixes;

- Added the markup for form enctype; `enctype="multipart/form-data`"
- Added a hidden `MAX_FILE_SIZE` attribute
- Not show in the code, i have tried adding size='30000000' in the file tag
- I've checked that the value / name are the same when setting and getting file
- I've also checked php.ini to ensure that file_upload is allowed

What could I possibly be missing?

Edit; I've tried this on my desktop and mobile browsers.

Comment: Have you checked your servers error log? And what are your file handling values in phpinfo() post_max_size, max_file_uploads, file_uploads etc

Comment: use `var_dump($_FILES)` and check.

Comment: post_max_size is 8m, upload_max_filesize is 2m, max_file_uploads is 20, file_uploads is on. checking var_dump($_Files) now

Comment: @YogeshSuthar var_dump($_FILES) returns array(0) { }, so it's not being passed through..but why...i've tried all of the things explained in my question.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. I have just tested your form and that uploads a file fine to a script which is just `<?php var_dump($_FILES);` , the problem has to be with either the file you are trying to upload, the browser or the server config. Silly question. how big is the file you are uploading? it isn't over 2mb is it?

Comment: It's a couple of hundred kb at max. perhaps it could be something deeper hidden, i'm using a mobile jquery library. i've looked through most of the server config and can't find anything out of the ordinary there that would be stopping me.

Comment: The way to find out is to just create a basic html file that only has the form above in it and see if it works then.

Comment: I made a file that just uploads to itself, and that seems to work fine. it must be in the transmission between the two pages.

Comment: Found the answer, was a problem with jquerymobile. Added as an answer to my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution to actually be a problem between the obvious (Not being able to file upload using ajax), and jquerymobile framework, which uses ajax on it's forms by default.

To fix the problem I added `data-ajax='false'`

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="decodeQR.php" method="post" data-ajax='false'>
```

The file upload works fine, so i'm posting this answer for anyone who's using jquerymobile and comes across this problem! : )

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the request sent by the browser contains the file?

BTW. I'm new here. How do you guys add these "comments" to questions?

Comment: I believe you need a certain rep before you can add comments. it's normally just under the question.